# "include_recipe" vs. Vagrantfile "chef.add_recipe". What's the difference?

Tags: nginx, vagrant, chef-recipe, chef-solo

Just ran nginx::source recipe on my vagrant box, and I have very unusual behaviour.

When I include a recipe from the **Vagrantfile** (as below), everything works like a charm,

> chef.add_recipe("project::nginx")
>   chef.add_recipe("nginx::source")

(*project::nginx* recipe is very simple. Using it to override default attributes of the nginx cookbook)

but if I include a recipe at the very end of **project::nginx** (mentioned up), everything falls apart:

```ruby
node.default['nginx']['server_names_hash_bucket_size'] = 128
include_recipe "nginx::source"
```

**Until now I didn't know there's any difference in behaviour between those two invocations. Does anybody here knows what's the difference?**

Comment: The snippet of code you provided, is that your attributes file or your recipe?

Comment: ah, it's the **project::nginx** recipe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gotya! Chef 11 feature. Issue with it exist in chef-solo solely :)

To make a quick resume, difference is:

- chef.add_recipe() - loads entire cookbook context (all the files, e.g. recipes, definitions, attributes...)
- include_recipe "" - files(attributes, definitions etc.) that are not in the expended run list are not loaded.

There are at least 4 ways to solve the issue(put files in the run list):

- include_attribute - include desired attribute file explicitly.
- metadata.rb->dependency - if your cookbook is using recipe from another cookbook, put that cookbook in metadata.rb's dependency section, and all it's files will be loaded.
- chef.add_recipe() - Load recipe via Vagrantfile. (Mentioned here just for reference)
- Berkshelf - you may use this cookbook manager to solve the issue as well. Here's the [Stackoverflow thread about this exact problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075061/chef-cookbook-fails-on-ohai-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass/20396483#20396483) and [some Docs](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/16/getting-started-writing-chef-cookbooks-the-berkshelf-way/)

For those who are interested in further reading, Chef 11 introduced dependency-based cookbook loading for non-recipe files. The new loading logic means that files belonging to cookbooks which exist in the cookbook_path but are not in the expanded run_list or dependencies of the cookbooks in the expanded run_list will no longer be loaded. REF: [Opscode breaking changes documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/breaking_changes_chef_11.html#non-recipe-file-evaluation-includes-dependencies), and if you need a signature of the error I got, [here's](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-2342) the exactly same one, even for the same cause.