# Cannot find a resource for nginx_site on ubuntu version 12.04

Tags: chef-solo

I am upgrading my chef version from 10.28 to 11.6, In almost every cookbook the resources definitions folder are not getting include in recipes file.

chef is throwing error

NameError

```
Cannot find a resource for <resource> on ubuntu version 12.04
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a Chef 11 "feature", already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361738/include-recipe-vs-vagrantfile-chef-add-recipe-whats-the-difference/20375077#20375077) on stackoverflow.

That post is mainly focused on missing attributes, but there is an issue with missing resources/definitions as well. If you follow the link you'll find couple of ways to solve the problem.

Although I think you already solved it by now, I hope this will help someone in the future :)

Comment: Thanks @konzula for the valuable inputs.
Yes, I have gone through the documentation and figured out that we need to include all dependency in metadeta.rb file, which will include all attributes, libraries and definition file.